# Is there a counterpart Java class of NSURLComponents in iOS?

Tags: java, android, ios

Does anyone know if there is a counterpart class in Java to be equivalent to `NSURLComponents` for iOS developers?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is the `java.net.URL` class which offers similar methods.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
String host = url.getHost();
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
String query = url.getQuery();
int port = url.getPort();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my question is that is there a class to generate rfc 3986 compliance URL in Java?